I'm trying to solve a captcha image I downloaded by editing a code on github
import keras
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
import imutils
from imutils import paths
import os
import os.path
import sys
import tensorflow

print(os.getcwd())
os.environ['TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS'] = '0'
captcha_image = ("c:/Users/micha/Documents/PythonProgramming/IG/captcha.jpg")
# Load the image and convert it to grayscale
image = cv2.imread(captcha_image)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

When I attempted to run the code with a file named 1.png I received this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
pytesseract_solver.py", line 14, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.10.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:196: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

I've searched this error but none of the results seems to be able to help my issue.
Added os.environ['TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS'] = '0' as suggested in a different post, but the error remains.

crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/im-trying-to-solve-a-captcha-image-i-downloaded-by-editing-a-code-on-github/18356

learn about the current working directory. you're a beginner. you haven't understood this concept yet. print(os.path.getcwd()) -- debug your code. you'll see where it fails and why. [mre] would stop somewhere close after the cvtColor call.

After trying the example code OpenCVs website it seems the captcha image is too small, I will try to resize it and try again

no, that's not it.

I get this when putting that line in the code;     print(os.path.getcwd())
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'ntpath' has no attribute 'getcwd'

@Christoph Rackwitz I can't seem to get the current working directory

oh, my mistake, it's just print(os.getcwd())

It seems captcha.jpg image is not read successfully. Because the error is saying "(-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'" means the image variable is most probably empty.

Could you please check if the image exists in that path?
Also, could you please check with the below codes if the image is read properly or not?  print(image) print(image.shape)


This is the result I got; [[[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
...
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]]
[[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
...
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]]
[[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
...
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]]
...
[[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
...
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]]
[[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
...
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]]

[[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
...
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]]
[[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
...
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]]
[[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
...
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]
[200 250 232]]]
(40, 152, 3)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\micha\Documents\PythonProgramming\IG\pytesseractsolver.py", line 179, in 
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.layers.convolutional'
